# how to hide home nav link in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, navigation

I'm trying to hide the home navigation link from the theme boilerplate that I downloaded from underscores.me. Wordpress codex says [that its not shown by default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_nav_menu), but whether I do this:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( array( 'show_home' => true ) ); ?>
```

Or this:

```
 <?php wp_page_menu( array( 'show_home' => false ) ); ?>
```

It still shows the home page nav link. When I don't call the `wp_page_menu` function it doesn't display the menus so I know its the one that's outputting it.
Any ideas what's wrong and what else could I try? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with a custom menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you could use a CSS approach. Try `display: none;`